# Scala @tailrec with fold

Tags: scala, recursion, fold

Does the scala's `@tailrec` annotation supports `Option.fold` method?

```
@tailrec
def test(a: Int): Int =
  if (a > 10)
    Option(true).fold(test(a - 1))(_ => test(a - 2))
  else
    -1
```

This code results in error:

> Could not optimize @tailrec annotated method test: it contains a
>   recursive call not in tail position

This problem can be solved with pattern matching but I find `fold` looks much cleaner.

Comment: what the point of using fold in this scenario? your method is always return -1. you do not need recursion at all :)

Comment: @Mr.V. It is just example scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to write a tail recursive function in Scala, your call to the tail recursive function needs to be in the last position (hence *tail call* recursion).

In your case `Option.fold` is last and the Scala compiler cannot figure out that the result of `fold` is always a call to `test`.

You can use [`TailCals`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.TailCalls$), to write a tail recursive function using `fold` :

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def test(a: Int): TailRec[Int] =
  if (a > 10) tailcall(Option(true).fold(test(a - 1))(_ => test(a - 2))) 
  else done(-1)

test(11).result // -1
```

It is for you to deside if you find using `TailRec` more concise than using pattern matching :

```
def test(a: Int): Int =
  if (a > 10) Option(true) match {
    case Some(_) => test(a - 2)
    case None => test(a - 1)
  }
  else -1
```

Comment: Thanks! With excess wrapper `tailcall` it looks less declaratively than with matching.