# Why can't Option.fold be used tail recursively in Scala?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, fold

Below, `sumAllIf` is tail recursive and `sumAllFold` is not. However, `sumAllIf` effectively has the same implementation. Is this a shortcoming of the Scala compiler (or of the Scala library), or am I overlooking something?

```
def maybeNext(in: Int): Option[Int] = if in < 10 then Some(in + 1) else None

// The Scala library implements Option.fold like this:
// @inline final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B =
//   if (isEmpty) ifEmpty else f(this.get)
@annotation.tailrec
def sumAllIf(current: Int, until: Int, sum: Int): Int =
  val nextOption = maybeNext(current)
  if (nextOption.isEmpty) sum else sumAllIf(nextOption.get, until, sum + nextOption.get)

// However, with Scala 3.1.0 and earlier, this is NOT tail recursive:
def sumAllFold(current: Int, until: Int, sum: Int): Int =
  maybeNext(current).fold(sum)(next => sumAllFold(next, until, sum + next))

@main def main(): Unit =
  println(sumAllIf(0, 10, 0))
  println(sumAllFold(0, 10, 0))
```

The issue is similar to question [Scala @tailrec with fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567145/scala-tailrec-with-fold), but here I'd like to find out *why* and whether this *could* be supported in the future.

The example is for Scala 3.1, but the issue itself is valid for Scala 2.x as well.

Comment: From the answer in the link you attached; "... the Scala compiler cannot figure out that the result of the fold" because the compiler cannot figure out the result of fold and thus couldn't make it tail-recursive.

Comment: This comes from the very definition of tail recursion. The call is not in the tail position and without inlining it is not obvious to the compiler how it could be optimized. If you really need tail recursion then write the recursion yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala @tailrec with fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567145/scala-tailrec-with-fold)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recursive call happens inside a lambda. So it is not a tail recursive call unless the compiler would inline the fold and the lambda into your own method and only then test whether it is tail recursive. However the compiler does not do that automatically and it probably never will do that automatically.

The good news is that in Scala 3 you can pretty easily work around that, and it is theoretically possible that the standard library will ever be adapted to take advantage of that. All it takes is explicitly implementing `fold` as an inline method with inline parameters.

```scala
inline def fold[A, B](opt: Option[A])(inline onEmpty: B)(inline f: A => B): B =
  opt match
    case Some(a) => f(a)
    case None => onEmpty

@annotation.tailrec
def sumAllFold(current: Int, until: Int, sum: Int): Int =
  fold(maybeNext(current))(sum)(next => sumAllFold(next, until, sum + next))
```

Note that an inline parameter automatically has by-name semantics, so `onEmpty` is already by-name without changing the type to `=> B`.

Comment: Thanks! Let's see, maybe we get this into the standard library? See https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/tailrec-support-for-option-fold/5546?u=georg

Answer (score 3):

> Below, `sumAllIf` is tail recursive and `sumAllFold` is not. However, `sumAllIf` effectively has the same implementation. Is this a shortcoming of the Scala compiler (or of the Scala library), or am I overlooking something?

This is simply the definition of *tail recursion*. A *tail call* is the last call in a subroutine. *Recursion* is when a subroutine calls itself. *Tail recursion* is when the tail call is a recursive call, or when the recursive call is in tail position – in other words, it is when a subroutine calls itself as the last call.

In your case, the last call is to `fold`, not to `sumAllFold`.

This is not a shortcoming of the Scala compiler or of the Scala library. `sumAllFold` isn't tail recursive, because its tail call is not the recursive call and the recursive call is not the tail call. In other words, it is not tail recursive, because it simply is not tail recursive.

This is basically the same as asking whether it is a shortcoming of your mechanic that your blue car isn't yellow. It is not. Your blue car isn't yellow because it simply isn't.